# Finite sparse collection in Scala

Tags: scala, data-structures, symbols

I'm doing a Base64 converter with Scala and I want to store a collection of symbols (Characters) mapped to indices. In Scala, the Char representation are ASCII codes. However, this collection of symbols have different sparse identifiers, i.e. 'A' corresponds to 65 and '+' corresponds to 43 and in between those values there are no valid symbols.

What I want to do is to map Base64 symbols to an index in Base64 (i.e. 'A' is 0) in order to decode a given string. I come up with a general trivial solution:

```
trait SymbolsTable {
  val symbols: IndexedSeq[Char] = 
    ('A' to 'Z') ++ ('a' to 'z') ++ ('0' to '9') ++ Seq('+', '/')

  val decodingTable: Map[Char, Int] = symbols.zipWithIndex.toMap[Char, Int]
}
```

Hence, I can get any index of the valid characters:

```
val indexA: Int = table.decodingTable('A')
```

I have to store only 64 symbols and we usually use Map to store an undefined number of keys. I'm curious if this can be done in another original way using others data structures as a Vector (in a dense way, without wasting memory).

Comment: Sparse collections are present in https://github.com/non/spire though other solutions might be better for this specific task.

Comment: Which one do you think is better?

Comment: I would go with existing libraries. I guess there are (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html) very good -already optimized, tested- solutions on the JVM, but probably you have different requirements.

Comment: Yes, I know the Base64 Decoder from Java but the point is to make my own library with Scala and try to optimize it the best I can. Thanks for your answer, though.

Comment: This kind of microoptimization doesn't come up often, if at all, in professional programming (at least IME). Certainly make sure you have a solid benchmark before trying it - otherwise how can you know whether you've made things any better? Scala does have optimized classes for very small fixed-size maps (see e.g. `Map4`) - you could perhaps generate a class like this using a macro. But honestly 64 is such a small number of entries that whether you use a `Map` or `Vector` or something else is very unlikely to make a difference to a real program. Don't optimize prematurely!

Comment: How much memory do you think a Map[Char,Int] with 64 entries is wasting? Are you sure it is worth optimizing?

Comment: Well, the main goal was to come up with an original way of do it without using the trivial solution. It isn't worth optimizing it. I only wanted the original solution to be optimal. As I'm learning functional programming, I was looking for another way of thinking. @Imm, thanks for the Map4 info, it's pretty interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I don't think this is worth optimizing at all, but just for kicks, you could do something like this, that would be really efficient memory-wise :)

```
def toBase64(c: Char): Int = c match {
   case '+' => 63
   case '/' => 64
   case x if 'A' to 'Z' contains x => c - 'A'
   case x if 'a' to 'z' contains x => c - 'a' + 26
   case x if '0' to '9' contains x => c - '0' + 52
   case _ => -1
}
```

Comment: With currying (`toBase64 _`), you can even make a function, just like `Map`. :)